# Rounding IEEE floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

I'm currently doing an assignment where I have to find the value of a given IEEE floating point representation. For the assignment, there is 1 singed bit, 5 exponent bits and 3 frac bits.

`The bits are : 1 11100 000`

Since the frac bits are all zeroes, I'm guessing that means the mantissa is going to inf. How do I round this? I know of rounding to even, but I don't know how exactly to use it. Some assistance would be great.

Comment: "I'm guessing that means the mantissa is going to inf" -> Nope.  [Some assistance would be great.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) is a nice example of 1, 5 10.  Should readily explain this one too.  I doubt any _rounding_ is needed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah I see. So I can just go with the usual -1^S * (1+M) + 2^E formula? If so, in what cases will it go to infinity and need rounding?

Comment: In IEEE-754 binary floating-point, infinity is represented with all ones in the exponent field and all zeroes in the significand field.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, that makes sense. Thank you clearing that up for me

Comment: @Uberi_Puip "usual -1^S * (1.0 +M) + 2^(E-[bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias)) formula?"

Comment: I meant the scientific representation of the floating point

Comment: Do you mean `(-1)^S * (1.0 +M*2^(-frac_bits)) * 2^(E-bias)`?

Comment: Also, there is no rounding when converting from a IEEE754 bit representation to the value it represents (but there is usually rounding necessary, if you want to represent the number with a (finite) number of decimals).

Comment: Normalized values always contain an implied 1 as the leftmost fraction bit, so "000" is really "1000". given 5 bits for the exponent, the offset would be  (2^4 - 1)=15. thus the exponent in the example is 15-e=28 or e = -13. Thus the number is -0.5x2*-13.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, as the mantissa always begins with a `1` digit, it is normally *implicit*, meaning that you have to add it to the left of the number.... in this case your number mantissa is `1000`.  Infinity should be if the exponent has it's maximum value, as in `1 11111 000` for minus infinity, and `0 11111 000` for plus infinity.